# I bought a domain, I configured Apache server on Windows but shows my IP instead of the URL

Tags: apache, url, dns

The title is quite descriptive, I bought a domain using Google Domains. I mount an Apache Server 2.4 in Windows 7. The problem is when i access the web url it shows the ip instead of the URL. I asked Google for this problem and they referred me to Apache configuration. But i don't find nothing in the Apache configuration to show the URL instead of the IP. Anyone can help?

Comment: Please post instead to serverfault.com your problem has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved. The problem was in Google Domain configuration in the DNS configuration. Ask Google they are really kind if you have the same issue.